# Showing exception when scroll down mobile app using touch action in appium

Tags: java, appium

I tried to scroll down the mobile app in order to click on a button below the screen.I have used below touch action for scrolling but it is giving an exception.Is there any other methods available? Anyone please help me to scroll down the mobile app.

Showing exception

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Swipe did not complete successfully

```
DesiredCapabilities androidCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver;
androidCapabilities.setCapability("automationName",PropertyUtility.getProperty("AndroidAutomationName"));       androidCapabilities.setCapability("platformName",PropertyUtility.getProperty("AndroidPlatformName"));
    androidCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", PropertyUtility.getProperty("AndroidPlatformVersion"));
    androidCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", PropertyUtility.getProperty("AndroidDeviceName"));
    androidCapabilities.setCapability("app",PropertyUtility.getProperty("AndroidAppPath"));
    androidCapabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
    androidCapabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "60");
    appiumDriver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), androidCapabilities);

    Dimension dim=appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println(dim);
    int x=dim.getWidth()/2;
    int startY=(int) (dim.getHeight()*(.8));
    int endY=(int) (dim.getHeight()*(.2));
TouchAction action=new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
action.press(PointOption.point(x,startY)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000))).moveTo(PointOption.point(x, endY)).release().perform();
```

**Configuration**

appium  1.15
java client : 7.3.0

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to scroll down a mobile app in order to click on a button displayed in the bottom.The button is showing only after the scrolling the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform scrolling to find particular element as follows:

```
public void scrollToElementByText(String text) {
        try {
            ((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("newUiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\").instance(0))");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Obviously, you can use any attribute to find an element (id, accessibility id etc) and then `click()` on that element. Or you can simply just scroll down and perform some check for your element to be displayed, and if not, keep scrolling down:

```
private void swipe(int xStart, int yStart, int xStop, int yStop) {
    try {
        new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(point(xStart, yStart))
                .moveTo(point(xStop, yStop)).release().perform();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       ...
    }
}

public void scrollDown() {
    swipe(5,
            (getWindowSize().getHeight()) - 200,
            5,
            100);
}

public void scrollToElement(MobileElement el) {
    while (true) {
        if (!el.isDisplayed()) {
            //element is not displayed, keep scrolling
            scrollDown();
        } else {
            //element found
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But be careful because you can get infinite loop with last method (implement your own logic for breaking that loop).

Comment: Thanks  . I have tried with the solution you are given it helped me to scroll down the mobile app .